# Revert a specific revision and commit to a new one

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, commit, subversion-edge

I use Tortoise as SVN client.

I need to update a few files to an old revision, then take the changes that this update creates and commit it to a new revision. Basically I wanna revert that revision in repository.

I know I can do it by creating a new working copy, using a compare-merge tool to to apply that working copy's changes into the main one, then commiting. But I'd rather do it with a unique working copy. It would be even better if I could use a command like `svn move` to make the change diretly in Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually trying to do a `reverse-merge`.

For example if your latest good code state was revision `42`, you can do it like this:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:42 .
```

and then commit it in the usual way.